# What's the correct usage of the word "Opinion"?

Tags: word-usage, example

I have been posting on a forum recently, and every time I express my opinion, someone says I'm using the word incorrectly, and I want to confirm this.

I said something along the lines of:
"In my opinion, this thing is bad"

Surely this acceptable? I would have thought the "In my opinion" would automatically render anything that follows part of my opinion, and not a fact that I am stating is true, so this would be the equivalent of "I think this thing is bad", would it not?

Otherwise, what is the correct usage of the word "opinion" in this context?

**Edit:** An addition to avoid confusion:

Take this example: "In my opinion, the realism in some videogames hinders the enjoyability, because etc.". This was actually the point I made in the first place, and the other person said that my opinion was invalid because there is evidence against my claim (as in they thought it didn't hinder the enjoyability), though I thought this was closer to the definition of "Fact".

Comment: In my opinion your thinking is perfectly correct.

Comment: @WS2, Unless in his opinion the statement that *two plus two equals four* is 'bad', because that is not a matter of opinion, but a matter of fact. Given that it would be very unlikely for native speakers would be *very* unlikely to dispute the usage of "opinion" *as shown*, there is very likely something else going on. OP, if you could share a couple of real-life, specific examples of "opinions" you've actually posted which people complained about (your usage of *opinion*), we can render a more authoritative judgement.

Comment: No, this was in fact an example I used to avoid confusion. Take this example: "In my opinion, the realism in some videogames hinders the enjoyability, because etc.". This was actually the point I made in the first place, and the other person said that my opinion was invalid because there is evidence against my claim (as in they thought it didn't hinder the enjoyability), though I thought this was closer to the definition of "Fact".

Comment: @DanBron There are two issues at play here a) grammatical correctness and b) what is opinion and what is fact?  If I say 'In my opinion two plus two equals five', that is perfectly grammatical English. Nonetheless it is completely illogical since arithmetic is not something where opinion counts, it is based on fact.

Comment: @Ws2, I don't think there's any question of grammatical correctness here; only on the proper usage and application of the word "opinion".

Comment: @DanBron Then is this an appropriate forum for determining what is governed by opinion and what by fact? That would not seem to be a question of English language, but of logic, metaphysics, or philosophy.

Comment: @Ambidextroid "Enjoyability" is unquestionably subjective, and any statement you render about a game's enjoyability is inevitably an opinion. You cannot "evidence" enjoyability; that's s category error. In the specific example you gave, you are 100% right and your friend is 100% wrong. Now, if he'd instead said "*More people* enjoy this game than dislike it", that's a quantitative statement, and could be substantiated with reference to user surveys, votes, and so forth.

Comment: @WS2 This is the appropriate forum for discussing the usage of "opinion" and whether it only properly applies to subjective statements. It's an elementary question, and the answer is *yes*. See above.

Comment: @DanBron At this point Plato might have asked 'What is justice?' Is it an opinion, or is it determinable? In other words is 'justice' what we, the electorate, make it? What then when the Platonist sitting on the front seat of the Clapham omnibus says 'In my opinion the law is unjust'? Is it something about which you can hold an opinion? All this seems to me well beyond the scope of English language.

Comment: @WS2, Again, OP *isn't* asking what is or isn't objective, or what is or isn't subjective, only whether the word "*opinion*" can be applied to objective statements.  It cannot. He then asks us to apply this observation; not in the general case, but to *one specific case* he has supplied. He is *not* asking about "justice", in fact, he is *only* asking about, "*enjoyability*" which is definitively subjective. That's all. It's a trivial question, but on topic. And it's been answered; let's move on. (PS: "Justice" is subjective, specifically bcause Platonic ideals *do not*, *objectively*, exist).

Comment: When you precede a statement with "In my opinion..." then the statement cannot be contradicted (except by you).  It may be that the statement exhibits your utter ignorance and stupidity, but it's still (unless you were lying) a "true" statement.  Someone else can say that your opinion is wrong (and foolish and idiotic), but that does not make your statement untrue, and it does not make the use of "opinion" improper.  (That's my opinion, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect we need more context in order to know what the person was reacting to.  While the particular sentence seems grammatically correct, there is a difference between "I think" and "in my opinion."

- "I think" means you believe the thing to be true.  You can say this about provable/disprovable facts.  For example, you can say "I think that tree is 100 feet tall," even though you could just measure the height of tree and figure it out for sure.  It just means you're making a guess, and you might be right or wrong.
- "In my opinion" is better used when expressing preference for subjective things.  "In my opinion, Michelangelo is a better artist than Da Vinci," is an example of a correct use.  For an example of a strange use: "In my opinion, spinach has more vitamin C per serving than oranges."  Since you can measure the vitamin C in these foods, you can't really have an opinion about them.

Comment: I've cleared some confusion in another comment above, though I'll edit the original queston.

Comment: According to dictionaries (OALD, M-W, CD), 'I think' is ambiguous, polysemous: it is also used with the intended meaning 'In my opinion, ...'. Yes, 'In my opinion' is the more precise expression, but 'I think he is a good man' obviously shows a value judgement.